# load hidden jsp page in javascript

Tags: jsp

I have a html page (build with xml en xsl). I want to update my database when someone visits the page with name user, date and page.

I thought to do it to add a javascript that update the database, but it is not a good idea because javascript is client based.

So I thought a could call a jsp file (where the code is written to update the database) when the html page loads.

The problem is that I don't know how to call the jsp file, without loading it in the browser.
I find on stackoverflow something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function updateStats(){
var jspcall="url.jsp"
window.location.href=jspcall
}
</script>
```

and then I tried with

```
<body onload="updateStats()">
```

But then ofcourse the page is loaded.
Someone an idea

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you want to do: If you plan on storing user data, users must enter that data first - so there is no point in storing it in a "hidden" way. Any user calling your pages must be aware that data on his visit might be stored, at least in the web server's access log.  If you absolutely want a HTML page to act dynamically without looking like it, you can either add AJAX functionality as proposed by others, or embed an iframe performing a POST request with the data you are interested in.

Comment: I want to store the date and the url page in a database to get track on how many times a page has been visited and when. The user don't have to click on anything, it has to be stored when the page is opening.

Comment: In that case you could use a Filter. It could do the work when the request is sent to your server.

Comment: @rickz Can you send me more info about that? I am not very well in programming and I am just a beginner.

Comment: It might be easier for you to use a logging framework. But if you want to learn about Filters, then you could google a lot of info. For instance   http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/05/10/servlet_filters.html    http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat/